Counting, rule for the presence of a slash at the end of the URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\..+ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

Redirect from www to without or from http protocol
I don't know how to check how to find out the number of redirects. In theory, this should be done in one, if both or one of the two rules does not match.
How to count the number of redirects (301) if you access the site via www and http?
How to add a rule if there is a slash at the end of the URL. In this case, redirect to without a slash.
